# rails - specifically including first record in list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I'm excluding the first row listed on my index page when displaying all records in a my Model called `Submitter` by using the following code:

submitters_controller.rb:

```
def index
@submitters = Submitter.where(:school_id =>@current_user.school_id).order('school_id,first_name').search(params[:search])[1..-1]
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @submitters }
end
end
```

However, I have a search option that needs to display the first row (especially when there is only 1 record to show). Is there a way to include in my Submitter.rb (Model) file that specifically includes the first row?

submitter.rb:

```
def self.search(search)
if search
  Submitter.find(:all, :conditions => ['first_name LIKE :search OR last_name LIKE :search', {:search => "%#{search}%"}])
else
  all
end
end
```

I tried adding [0..-1] to the end of my `Submitter.rb` Model, which allows me to do the search now, but first record is still hidden. I know that it's working tho because when there are multiple results i can see all after the first row listed:

```
if search
  Submitter.find(:all, :conditions => ['first_name LIKE :search OR last_name LIKE :search', {:search => "%#{search}%"}])[0..-1]
else
```

Comment: is this a rails 3 app?

Comment: Yes it is. Rails 3.2.11

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
 def self.search(search)
  if search.present?
    search_query = Submitter.where('first_name LIKE :search OR last_name  LIKE:search', {:search => "%#{search}%"})
    if search_query.count > 1
      result = search_query.offset(1)
    else
      result = search_query
    end
  else
    return self.all
  end
  result.all
end
```

Comment: `submitter.rb:37: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end`

Comment: Thanks for helping. Your code makes sense to me logically, however when I search a keyword with the updated code, nothing happens. No results load and the full list remains, just the page refreshes.

Comment: @Devin try using debugger and see does it passes the if condition 'search.present?'

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not familiar with debugger. Is that a gem?

Comment: @Devin, yes watch this http://railscasts.com/episodes/54-debugging-with-ruby-debug, gut in rails 3 use 'debugger' same which gives you same functionality.